# Calling a function (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I came across question that I think might help me complete a project I'm working on. I was a bit confused about one aspect of it, and I was wondering if someone might be able to clarify what is being done. The answer comes from this question: [Adding Missing Dates in MongoDB Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076351/adding-missing-dates-in-mongodb-aggregation/62092767#62092767)

I'm just confused on the final part.

```
//You can call this function like so
$agg = fillEmptyDates(
            $agg, 
            { Count: 0, AverageIncome: 0 },
            req.query.from,
            req.query.to,
        )
```

How and where would you call this function? From what I know,`function $agg = fillEmptyDates(...)` wouldn't be proper syntax for javascript, so I'm just a bit confused.

Also, this is more for a formatting/structural question, but should the javascript code be within the same document? For instance, should it be right before?

```
expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
const $agg = await Subscription.aggregate([
...
])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$agg` is the returned result from the function `fillEmptyDates` call. According to the code, it is an array with sorted order, not a function to be called.